# How to store data in browser?

Tags: reactjs, session

**BACK STORY:** I am creating a react app which uses back-end-api JSON based authentication for log-in, after user is validated back-end returns a JSON token for future requests.

**WHAT AM I DOING NOW:** I am passing down that token from one component to another using `props` (and yes, that's not very elegant nor clean).

**WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR:** Someone after seeing the project suggested me to store the token & other redundant data in browser memory. Now, I don't know how to do that nor I was able to find any resources.

**BUT:** I believe that this problem can be solved by `redux`. But I want to create a react only app first before jumping to `redux` or some other advanced stuffs.

- So, how do I store these type data in browser memory itself?
- Or, is there any more elegant solution to this?
- Also, gimme some advice about session management. Like when token expires the user is shown a dialog and redirected back to login page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not you simply go for `LocalStorage` ? like this

```
localStorage.setItem('user_info', JSON.stringify(response));
```

For more info refer here

- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

## Update

To get values from `locastorage` you can use the syntax below -

```
localStorage.getItem('user_info');
```

Comment: Is it react compatible? Can I store values form `props` or `state` to it? How can I get back values?

Comment: its not about react or angular specific, its functionality provided by browser , you can use it anyway. see my Updated answer

Comment: You can store value in props or state but when u refresh a browser 
you will lose the value. LocalStorage or cookies help u to hold token after refreshin or closing browser

Comment: I noticed that w3school link states that there is a storage limit per browser.  I wonder whether there is a way to increase the limit (Google doesn't show me much).

Comment: Yes there is limit on storage which is browser specific, I don't think so we can increase this limit.

Answer (score 0):

Redux is a state container for react. It helps you to manage all states in react app. But you can still live without it (barely) using local state and props. Besides, you can use localStorage and cookies to store whatever you want.